# London where he comes from or London from where he comes?

Tags: relative-clauses

> 1. He comes from London.
> 2. He goes to London.

If we use **London** as an **antecedent** in a noun clause.what are the correct noun clauses given below?

> 1. (a) London where he comes from.
>        (b) London from where he comes.
>        (c) London (that/which) he comes from.
>        (d) London from which he comes.
> 2. (a) London where he goes to.
>        (b) London to where he goes.
>        (c) London (that/which) he goes to.
>        (d) London to which he goes.

Comment: London is the place/city he comes from and the similar changes to all.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use **which** with city names.

Ungrammatical things <del>stricken</del> below.

1.(a)London, where he comes from...    (OK in conversational speech, but prescriptive grammarians do not like to end the clause with a preposition)

(b)London, from where he comes...

<del>(c)London, (that/which) he comes from.</del>

<del>(d)London, from which he comes.</del>

London, whence he comes   (formal, more often heard in British English that American)

2.
(a)London, where he goes <del>to</del> to get his suits tailored

(b)London, <del>to</del> where he goes. ....

<del>(c)London (that/which) he goes to.</del>

<del>(d)London to which he goes.</del>

**The Tower of London, to which he goes every year...** would be OK.

Comment: I think that the supposed rule about not ending a clause with a preposition is pretty much discredited as a "zombie rule". 1(b) seems very stilted and if somebody were going to try to be that formal they'd almost certainly go all the way to "...whence he comes" (or, more likely, get it wrong with "...from whence he comes").

Comment: But you do run into people who consider the practice "bad writing". They might even be people making hiring decisions. It's not a bad idea to make people aware that the prohibition still has some currency.

Comment: If you're going to have "whence he comes" might as well list "whither he goes" for completeness. Nobody actually says it, except maybe folk singers and people intentionally sounding archaic ;-)